# SWRevealViewController how to know which frontViewController has called the RearViewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm using `SWRevealViewController`.  My `frontViewController` displays the various different content of the app and the `rearViewController` displays a table with links to those options.  So if my frontViewController is currently display the Home page I want the `rearViewController` menu table to highlight that row, and so on for each of the other options.  To do this the menu or `rearViewController` needs to know which view is being displayed by the `frontViewController`.  I have tried setting a `restorationIdentifier` on each of the `ViewControllers` displayed by the `frontViewController` and then accessing them in the menuViewcontroller but each time they return `nil`.

So I was doing something like this in the `menuViewControllers viewDidLoad` method

```
self.revealViewController.frontViewController.restorationIdentifier
```

I also set the restorationIdentifiers on VC Views and tried this:

```
self.revealViewController.frontViewController.view.restorationIdentifier
```

but that also returned null

Answer (score 0):

I think when you're in `viewDidLoad`, the reveal controller hasn't hooked up to the rear view or possibly even the front VC yet. So you're getting nil from `self.revealViewController` is my guess.

Try this in `viewWillAppear` instead.

Comment: Yep I tried that as well. I should have stated in the question.  Same result

Comment: What is returning nil then? self.revealViewController? self.revealViewController.frontViewController? Or just the restorationId?

Comment: The restorationId.  I've implemented a work around based on the selected cell of the table, I can figure out what was the last option that the user pressed and therefore in (most) cases it is the content that is currently in the frontViewController.  I also tried setting tags on the views presented by the frontviewController but these always evaluated to 0 even when I had set different values to them in the storyboard.

Comment: I would double check the class of self.revealViewController.frontViewController, it might not be what you expect. For example, it might be your app's UINavigationController or tab controller. In that case you'll have to dig a bit deeper to reach the VC you want.